# how to limit the trigger of DroneCi pipeline to be promote on default branch only

Tags: drone.io

I'm currently using this yml

```
kind: pipeline
type: docker
name: promote-main

trigger:
  branch:
    - master
  event:
    - promote
  target:
    - prod
```

but I still see this pipeline run when I raise a pull request against a branch.

How can I prevent this pipeline from being triggered from a build based on a branch?

I tried all these combinations, but nothing worked:

```
trigger:
  branch:
    - master
  exclude:
    - "*/**"
  event: 
    - promote
  target:
    - prod
```

```
trigger:
  branch:
    include:
      - master
    exclude:
      - "*/**"
  event: 
    - promote
  target:
    - prod
```

```
trigger:
  event:
    - promote
  target:
    - prod
  source:
    - master
```

```
trigger:
  ref:
    - refs/heads/master
  event:
    - promote
  target:
    - prod
```